# Django not displaying images after adding product details

Tags: python, django

Django can be able to display the image if I comment out the product details page.

I would like to know why it does that and how can I make it always display the images.

#### Product model

```py
item_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    item_description = models.TextField(
        max_length=200, verbose_name="Item Description")
    item_price = models.FloatField(default=0.00)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, unique=True)
    item_details = models.TextField(
        max_length=1000, verbose_name="Item Details")
    item_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    item_availability = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_item_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_item_recommended = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # Todo: add Is On Carousel Filter
    item_brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_categories = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/product/',
                              default="images/product/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg")
```

#### Product Views

```py
class HomePageView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'product/index.html'

class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'product/product_list.html'

def product_detail(request, slug):
    objec = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug)
    template_name = 'product/product_detail.html'

    return render(request, template_name, context={'object': objec})
```

#### Product Templates

```html
{% for product in object_list %}

          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="product-grid4">
              <div class="product-image4">
                <a href="product/{{ product.slug }}">
                  <!-- <img src="{{ product.item_brand.brand_image.url }}" alt="{{ product.item_brand.brand_name }}" width="30px"> -->
  
                  <img class="pic-1" src="{{ product.item_image.url }}" alt="{{ product.item_name }}">
                </a>
                <!-- <span class="product-new-label">Recommended</span> -->
                <!-- <span class="product-discount-label">-10%</span> -->
              </div>
              <div class="product-content">
                <h3 class="title"><a href="#">{{ product.item_name }}</a></h3>
                <div class="price">
                  Kshs. {{product.item_price }}
                  <!-- <span>$16.00</span> -->
                </div>
                <a class="add-to-cart" href="{% url 'add-to-cart' product.slug %}">ADD TO CART</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
{% endfor %}
```

#### Product Urls

```py
    url(r'product/(?P<slug>.+)$', views.product_detail, name='product-detail'),
    url('^$', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name='landing_page'),
    url('shop/', views.ProductListView.as_view(), name="product-list")
```

#### Settings.py

```py
.....

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]


# Simplified static file serving.
# https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

### The error I get. Please note the error only comes up when `product_detail` view and it's url are called. When they are commented out, the images are displayed.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/product/airmax_98_bVXgZPB.jpg
Raised by:  shop.views.product_detail
No Product matches the given query.
```

Comment: Hi, have you added the media and static files urls in your root urls config?

Comment: Yes, they are properly configured.

Comment: just to double check, can you add your root urls file contents to the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with how the url is being displayed.

I should Use `path` instead of `url` like so:

#### Product Urls

```py
......
    path('product/<slug>/', views.product_detail, name='product-detail'),
    path('shop/', views.ProductListView.as_view(), name="product-list"),
......
```

I still don't have a clear understanding as to why I should use `path` instead of `url`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want have problems when you change urlpattern, you should replace `<a href="product/{{ product.slug }}">` to `<a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">` and add a bit of code to models.py

```
*product fields goes here*
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product-detail', args=[self.slug])
```

And don't forget `from django.urls import reverse`
I've noticed that your django is not pretty new, and if `Can not import reverse from django.urls`

Comment: I am using `django==2.2.13`. However, it is still not displaying the images

Comment: Does name and price displayed in list view?

Comment: And please provide settings.py with your replaced data

Comment: Yes, name and price are displayed.

Comment: I have provided settings.py with the required data

Comment: Try collectstatic command, and there probably will be an error, this is due to whitenoise or django itself, a had the same issue, for serving files better use something like Apache or nginx. I know there is a lot of benefits but I haven’t found the way to solvethe problem. Try collect static and search the error it gives